# test related to get time and comparison failed when run in docker container

Tags: docker, datetime, robotframework

I have a script that uses GET TIME  and do a comparison later on.

The test passed at my local machine and printed the time same as my machine time e.g.  09:37:57  is printed when my machine shows morning 9 am.

however, when I run the test in a docker container, the test failed, the time printed is 01:37:57.

Should I set something in docker to make it uses the same timezone as my server/app timezone?

how to get rid of such a problem, because of the different format in a docker container, the comparison test failed.

```
Get Current Audio Upload Time
    ${time}=      Get Current Date
    ${current-time}=      Convert Date      ${time}      result_format=%H:%M:%S
    Log To Console     time when uploading audio is ${current-time}
    Set Global Variable    ${current-time}
```

The comparison to use above time to compare the time displayed at web page.

```
Verify Audio Time
    ${time-elem}    Get Table Cell Element   .ant-table-content > table   "Time"    "Dual-Channel-Audio-${RandomNumber}"
    ${UI-time}     Get Text    ${time-elem}
    Log To Console   time displayed at UI is ${UI-time}

    ${time-substract-result}=  Subtract Time From Time     ${UI-time}    ${current-time}
    Log To Console    subtract time is ${time-substract-result}
    Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    Should Be True   ${time-substract-result} <= 300    time displayed at UI is more than 5 seconds than expected time
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried setting up this in Dockerfile and issue resolved.

```
ENV TZ 'Asia/Singapore'
```